# Setting Attribute to a div in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, attributes

I've got a Vue file and I would like to set an 'action' attribute of my form.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

export default {
  created() {
    var test = document.getElementById("form");
    test.setAttribute('action', 'file.php');
  }
```

But setting it in a lifecycle hook doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: You don't have an ID.

Comment: You should do this within Vue (bind the attribute), not by using the DOM directly.

Comment: Yeah, thanks it was unnecessary question, it worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

1. The `mounted` lifecycle hook is usually where you want to perform the initial actions for the component
2. Using `getElementById` goes against the way Vue is supposed to be used

Something like this would make more sense:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form :action='action'>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      action: 'file.php'
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // initialize things here
  }
}
```